# Upload 1500 products in 1.13, but it we need to click save on every one to go live

Tags: enterprise-1.13

Would very much like you help. We are uploading 1500 products and the content and images are all in properly. However to get them to show up in frontend, we have to hit save on very product then reindex. Any way to do this once?

Comment: `php shell/indexer.php reindexall` ??

Comment: A reindex or you are missing an attribute and the manual save clears the field. That you do not know this and it is with Enterprise is the more troubling problem.

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because these products do not have a correct stockitem with them. The stock table has quantity and a few other things in it, this data is needed if products are to show on the back end.

By manually resaving you are creating that stock item. Try to mass update the 'in stock' or 'qty' for those products and see if they show then.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the same thing as nachito, login to your shell cli, go to your Magento root -> shell then run

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

This will force all indexes to be re-built and should update all your product data in the process so it will display on the front end.

Be sure to refresh your cache afterwards if you don't have it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Vallier's answer should work for you.

n98-magerun.phar is a great tool for running magento commands easily too:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

And for bulk import plus on the fly re-indexing its hard to go past MAGMI:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git
Super fast imports and, once you get the hang of the import CSV format, its really good for on-the-fly category creation, image import and reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

simply run your cron, it will re-index all your data,

eg. siteurl.com/cron.php

now check your `index management' and`Products`